# Using videoGrabber with ofMesh in OpenFrameworks on iOS

Tags: ios, openframeworks

First time diving into OF on iOS...exciting! As a first run I'm trying to port an app I made before into an iOS app. Its a pretty simple rutt etra-like effect on video coming in from the video camera. I have it working as a mac app, but I can't seem to get it displaying properly on my iPhone. The mesh is drawing, but I don't think I'm getting pixel values from my camera to vidPixels in order to change the color of my mesh. I'm basing this off of the videoGrabberExample in OF iOS 0072. I'm on a MacBook Pro, 10.7.5, running Xcode 4.5.2.

Can anyone give this a look and let me know if I'm doing something wrong? :) Thanks so much in advance.

Code:

testApp.mm

```
#include "testApp.h"
#include "ofGLUtils.h"
#include "ofGLRenderer.h"

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::setup(){  
ofxiPhoneSetOrientation(OFXIPHONE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_RIGHT);

ofSetFrameRate(30);

grabber.initGrabber(480, 360);

yStep = 5;
xStep = 5;

  //  drawRuttEtra = false;

ofBackground(0, 0, 0);

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::update(){
//ofBackground(255,255,255);

grabber.update();

if(grabber.isFrameNew()){
vidPixels = grabber.getPixelsRef();
}

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::draw(){   

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    ofMesh mesh;

    int rowCount = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y<grabber.height; y+=yStep){
        ofNoFill();
        mesh.setMode(OF_PRIMITIVE_LINE_STRIP);

        if (rowCount % 2 == 0) {
            for (int x = 0; x < grabber.width; x += xStep){
                ofColor curColor = vidPixels.getColor(x, y);
                mesh.addColor(ofColor(curColor));
                mesh.addVertex(ofVec3f(x,y, curColor.getBrightness() * 0.3));
            }
        } else {
            for (int x = grabber.width-1; x >= 0; x -= xStep){
                ofColor curColor = vidPixels.getColor(x, y);
                mesh.addColor(ofColor(curColor));
                mesh.addVertex(ofVec3f(x,y, curColor.getBrightness() * 0.3));                    }
        }
        rowCount++;
    }
    mesh.draw();
   // grabber.draw(0,0);
}
```

testApp.h

```
#pragma once

#include "ofMain.h"
#include "ofxiPhone.h"
#include "ofxiPhoneExtras.h"

class testApp : public ofxiPhoneApp{

public:
    void setup();
    void update();
    void draw();
    void exit();

    void touchDown(ofTouchEventArgs & touch);
    void touchMoved(ofTouchEventArgs & touch);
    void touchUp(ofTouchEventArgs & touch);
    void touchDoubleTap(ofTouchEventArgs & touch);
    void touchCancelled(ofTouchEventArgs & touch);

    void lostFocus();
    void gotFocus();
    void gotMemoryWarning();
    void deviceOrientationChanged(int newOrientation);

    ofVideoGrabber grabber;
    ofTexture tex;
    unsigned char * pix;

    //rutt etra effect

    int yStep;
    int xStep;
    bool drawRuttEtra;

    ofPixels vidPixels;

};
```

main.mm

```
#include "ofMain.h"
#include "testApp.h"

int main(){
ofSetupOpenGL(1024,768, OF_FULLSCREEN);         // <-------- setup the GL context
ofRunApp(new testApp);
}
```

I tried doing some debugging to see what might be happening.

I wanted to make sure ifFrameNew() works. Trying:

```
if(grabber.isFrameNew()){  
   cout<< "i'm grabbing new pixels!" << endl;  
vidPixels = grabber.getPixelsRef();  
}
```

prints "i'm grabbing new pixels!", so that if block is working.

In my double for loop, if I cout the value of vidPixels.getColor(x,y)

```
cout<<vidPixels.getColor(x,y) << endl;
```

I get all 255...which makes me think grabber.getPixelsRef() isn't working how I thought it should.

Any ideas?